# Simplify a conditional statement - only wrap a component in a tooltip if

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below I have wrapped a Tooltip component around my ListItemText component in case the title text is too long and gets truncated.

Unfortunately I had to copy the ListItemText component down in the else-clause which makes the code really ugly. Is there a way to simplify this?

```js
return (
            <MenuItem id={id}
                selected={selected}
                className={`${classes.menuItem} ${menuItemClassName}`}
                button
                dense
                classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
                onClick={onSelect}>
                {children}
                {title.length > 30 &&
                    <Tooltip title={title}>
                        <ListItemText
                            style={nested ? { paddingLeft: 32 } : undefined}
                            className={classes.attributeItem}
                            classes={{ primary: classes.attributeText }}>
                            {title}
                        </ListItemText>
                    </Tooltip>
                }
                {
                    30 > title.length &&
                        <ListItemText
                            style={nested ? { paddingLeft: 32 } : undefined}
                            className={classes.attributeItem}
                            classes={{ primary: classes.attributeText }}>
                            {title}
                        </ListItemText>
                }
            </MenuItem>
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just an irrelevant question here.. what should happen if the title.length is exactly 30 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that storing it into a variable is a first step to avoid redundancy

```js
const MyListItemText = (
  <ListItemText
    style={nested ? { paddingLeft: 32 } : undefined}
    className={classes.attributeItem}
    classes={{ primary: classes.attributeText }}>
     {title}
  </ListItemText>);
return (
            <MenuItem id={id}
                selected={selected}
                className={`${classes.menuItem} ${menuItemClassName}`}
                button
                dense
                classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
                onClick={onSelect}>
                {children}
                {title.length > 30 &&
                    <Tooltip title={title}>
                        {MyListItemText}
                    </Tooltip>
                }
                {
                    30 > title.length && {MyListItemText}
                }
            </MenuItem>
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a variable before your `return` statement and use a ternary condition to improve readability :

```
const listItemNode = (
    <ListItemText
        style={nested ? { paddingLeft: 32 } : undefined}
        className={classes.attributeItem}
        classes={{ primary: classes.attributeText }}>
        {title}
    </ListItemText>
)

return (
    <MenuItem id={id}
        selected={selected}
        className={`${classes.menuItem} ${menuItemClassName}`}
        button
        dense
        classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
        onClick={onSelect}>
        {children}
        {title.length > 30 ?
            <Tooltip title={title}>{listItemNode}</Tooltip>
            :
            {listItemNode}
        }
    </MenuItem>
);
```

Is something else supposed to happen when the length is `30` ?

Comment: I am aware of the length 30 case, but will change it now. Nothing special supposed to happen.